# Custom UITableViewCell height with line breaks

Tags: uitableview

Setting custom UITableViewCell height dynamically. If the text contain line breaks, the calculated height is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{         
        CGSize constraintSize = {320.0, 20000};
        CGSize neededSize = [_beerDetails.notes sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        return neededSize.height + 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should your width in 'constraintSize' not be less than 320 (as this is the full width of the iPhone screen)? You could maybe try a width of 300 or 290.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried a few values for 'constraintSize', and 273 works out best.